# Custom annotations for authorization in play framework

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.2

Hello first things first: Im using play framework 2.2.3 for java.

Basic tutorial about authentication in play shows how to use Annotation Security.Authenticated. The problem is that whole my application (besides login and registry forms) needs to be secured.

Now I thought of overloading GlobalSettings onRequest method and include my authentication inside, so every single call of an action would perform authentication check.

But I was told its not elegant way and was told to create another annotation similar to Security.Authenticated, but working on a whole class instead of method, and put it into my custom abstract controller class, so all my controllers that extends it will inherit this annotation.

Now I'm wondering how to make this annotation. Any tips ? Where should I start ? I know basics, how to code annotation itself, but i dont know where is right place to get annotations of controllers class to check if it contains my custom annotation, and perform authentication if so.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an authorization + authentication plugin for Play that can secure the whole class, and hence all the action methods within it, try SecureSocial. It has its own set of annotations, and securing every action method in a class is as easy as doing:

```
@SecureSocial.SecuredAction 
public class MyController extends Controller {
```

Yes it's a little bit more work than intercepting the request and doing your check there, but its a more flexible method in case you'd like to "unsecure" some of the actions later on.